# Conway's Game on weird surfaces

Tags: python

I was reading Conway's Game of Life article on Wikipedia and I saw this gif. It is a simulation of the game of life on a trefoil knot. I think the gif is pretty cool and I wonder if I can implement this on python.

[image: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/64/Trefoil_knot_conways_game_of_life.gif]

The point is that drawing a trefoil knot is easy. But I am not sure how can I play the game on this surface since I cannot get the position as a 2D vector (for example normally I would say: alive[2][3] or dead[1][5]). Mathematically speaking, I can say that the position is a 3D vector x,y,z (spherical coordinates may be a better approach in this case, I am not sure) then I can manipulate these coordinates to play the game. I am used to using linear algebra in python, but the linear algebraic approach probably would not work here.

Any ideas on how to implement the game and play it by passing the initial points?

Simple knot, set p,q=(3,2) for trefoil:

```
def sample(phi, p, q, r1, r2, out):
    out.x = (r1 + r2 * cos(p * phi)) * cos(q * phi)
    out.y = (r1 + r2 * cos(p * phi)) * sin(q * phi)
    out.z = r2 * -sin(p * phi)

def torusknot(tess_u, tess_v, p, q):

    vertices = []
    pt_tk = vec3()
    pt_tk_next = vec3()
    pt_c = vec3()

    r1, r2, r3 = 5, 2, 0.5
    p, q = 7, 3

    for u in range(tess_u):
        phi = (u / tess_u) * 2 * pi
        sample(phi, p, q, r1, r2, pt_tk)

        phi = (u + 1) * 2 * pi / tess_u
        sample(phi, p, q, r1, r2, pt_tk_next)

        sample(phi, p, q, r1, 0, pt_c)

        T = (pt_tk_next - pt_tk)
        B = normalize(pt_tk - pt_c)
        N = normalize(cross(T, B))
        T = normalize(cross(B, N))

        for v in range(tess_v):
            theta = (v / tess_v) * 2 * pi
            px = sin(theta) * r3
            py = cos(theta) * r3
            pp = N * px + B * py + pt_tk
            vertices.append(pp * 10)

    return vertices
```

Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life#Algorithms

Comment: Even though the knot is 3-dimensional, its surface is just 2-dimensional, just like the surface of a sphere (you only need latitude and longitude, not altitude).

Comment: Of course, since the screen is self is 2D. But how would you get the position of a given cell on a knot (in 2D)?

Comment: No, that's not what I'm talking about. Pick an arbitrary point on the trefoil, call that 0,0. All the other points can be reached by going around the circumference (X coordinate) and along the length (Y coordinate). Both of them wrap around, but it's common to define the normal flat life as wrapping.

Answer (score 0):

I would map the playing surface as 2D space with wrapping at each edge. The 3D trefoil looks complicated, but topologically it is just a cylinder that connects at the ends, and a cylinder is just a surface that wraps at two edges.

So, set up the game on a 2D plane with wrapping at all edges, and then render it in this trefoil shape afterward.

Comment: I guess what you're defining is a torus. If we're talking about trefoil knots and making cylinder analogy, I guess it would be some multiple nested end-to-end connected cylinders.

Comment: Why is that? If you cut the knot anywhere, you are left with what is essentially a pipe, which is just a twisted cylinder. I know that in terms of formal topology none of my descriptions and operations are valid, but if we are just trying to solve the programming issue, it is fine.

Comment: That's correct, for some reason, when you said connect the ends of the cylinder, I was not thinking about tortion so naturally, I thought it was a torus. Actually topologically speaking, all of the trivial (can untie) knots are equivalent to a torus since you can get a torus from a knot only by bending, without cutting or making a hole in it.

Comment: I am actually quite curious about seeing if I can make this work too. What libraries are you using for the 3D stuff?  I have literally no experience with working with graphics, 3D or otherwise, so I wasn't able to do much with the code you provided. No idea where vec3(), normalize(), and cross() are from, for example, or what type is tess_u and tess_v. Are those types and functions you implemented yourself?

Comment: Yes, I understand the confusion, I did not share all of the code because generally, I get a warning that I should not include irrelevant code to the question. I also have a little experience in 3D. I am using OpenGL. vec2 is provided by the glm library, it is a utility class representing a 2D vector. I recommend you take a look at OpenGL and GLM.

Comment: Generating 3D objects is rather trivial in python (thanks to these libraries). I am working on it at the moment. 
If you can make this work, let me know